# How do i align a button image with the size of the actual button?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've been messing with android recently and i've gotten up to the point of changing the look of buttons. I've created an xml file in drawables for the state of the button and created an android:background="" line to refer to the xml. I've been searching for quite some time and it looks like no one else has asked the question.

This is what I get:

[image]

This is where the buttons are suppose to go:

[image]

How/Where would I set the size of the button image to match the actual button?

Also an additional sort of Off Topic question.

How do i make the image to only show the button and not the transparent parts of the image?

Comment: We can't help you without seeing your XML code

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create 9-patch background image for your button.
Here is about 9-patch information: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Comment: I created 9-patch background images for it but the size is still messed up like in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use 9 patch images to make them stretch over the button. [this link](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html)  will help you create a 9 patch image